# Shopify PUT request failing with 404 on OPTIONS preflight

Tags: http, shopify, axios, put, http-options-method

I am using AXIOS from within my app to access the shopify admin api. I am updating a customer with metafields (which, as I understand it, the storefront API does not support with graphql). I am receiving a preflight options error when I do a PUT. The error is a 404. The item I am trying to hit does in fact exist so I am wondering if shopify is mishandling the request or if I am missing something in my configuration.

Note: I am successfully able to do the same request through Postman. Postman is not doing an options preflight as far as I know.

My code:

```
axios({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: `https://${SHOPIFY_SHOP}/admin/customers/${decodedId}.json`,
    auth: {
      username: SHOPIFY_BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME,
      password: SHOPIFY_BASIC_AUTH_SECRET,
    },
    data: {
      customer: {
        id: decodedId,
        metafields: [
          {
            namespace: 'custom_fields',
            key: 'organization',
            value: org,
            value_type: 'string',
          },
          {
            namespace: 'custom_fields',
            key: 'token_pro',
            value: isPro,
            value_type: 'integer',
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  }).then((data) => {
    debugger
  }).catch(( error ) => {
    debugger
  });
```

The errors

```
OPTIONS https://SHOP_NAME.myshopify.com/admin/customers/776734343229.json 404 (Not Found)

Failed to load https://SHOP_NAME.myshopify.com/admin/customers/776734343229.json: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Note that the customer does in fact exist at the time of this axios call.